# Proving $\ker(F)\neq\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been posed this question:

Suppose that $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear transformation and that $m<n$. Use the Dimension Theorem to prove that $\ker(F)\neq\{0\}$. (Hint: $\mathcal{R}(F)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$ - what does that tell you about the rank of $F$?)

I'm stuck with how to go about proving this question. All I could gather from the hint is that the rank of $F\leq m$ and I'm not even sure that is correct.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: State the dimension theorem. See where the rank and the dimension of the kernel come in.

Comment: Please use mathjax to typeset your question

Comment: Hint: $rank(F)\leq m<n$

Comment: so far, i have: dimension theorem: $rank(A) + dimNul(A) = n$.  Alternatively, $rank(A) + dimKer(F) = n$. Since $rank(F)=rank(A) \leq m$, $dimKer(F) = n-rank(A) \geq 0$ since, $rank(F) \leq m<n$

Comment: If $\mbox{rank } A = \mbox{rank } F$, then $\mbox{rank } A < n$ as well, so $\dim \ker F = n - \mbox{rank } A$ is?

Comment: ... greater than 0?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Now since $\dim\ker F>0,\ker F\ne\{\mathbf 0\}$ as $\dim\{\mathbf 0\}=0$

Comment: Exactly. It is positive. Now, that of course means that the kernel contains some vector other than zero, because the dimension of the zero subspace is zero. That completes the argument Write an answer below yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You know that since F is linear $dim(Ran(F))+dim(Ker(F))=n$ so, like you said, $dim(Ran(F))\le m$. For equality to be true, it is necessary that $dim(Ker(F))>0$ so $Ker(F)\neq\{0\}$.